# Error response from daemon when starting a docker container

Tags: docker

When I type `docker start projects` I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\"/bin/bash”\\": stat /bin/bash”: no such file or directory\"\n"
>   Error: failed to start containers: projects

What should I do so I can start my docker containers?

Comment: What is the entrypoint for the image? Also, this could be a permissions issue, could you try running as sudo?

Comment: please edit the question and post results of `docker inspect projects`?

Comment: Try `/bin/sh` to see if you have a shell to work with.

Comment: check volume mounts in `docker-compose.yml` file. it looks like you are overwriting command from compose file and executing a script which you forgot to mount in `volumes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible errors

1. The file or directory you are mapping is invalid
2. The base image you are using do not have /bin/bash

and try to start a new container instead of old one from docker run projects

Comment: My docker container had no directory. I fixed it by creating a new one from scratch.